How get PDF/A compliance with fpdf2
I am able to generate a pdf with fpdf2 but I want it to show up with the PDF/A compliance tag in Adobe Acrobat Reader. Basically i want the below text to appear when the PDF is opened.

Do I need to need to signing to make this PDF/A compliant?
Something like:
pdf.sign_pkcs12("certs.p12", password=b"1234")

fpdf2 in the current/latest version 2.8.1 does not support PDF/A accessibility.
There is an open feature request on GitHub about that: https://github.com/py-pdf/fpdf2/issues/262
